# Classes can't be found in Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, package, rinsim

I suddenly encountered the following problem: it does not recognise certain class files from the dependencies.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O144a.png)

Thinking it was because of my installation, I re-installed everything from Java to the Maven Plugin and tried to compile and run the SimpleExample from a clean project. Which gives the following result: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m11wK.png) and the following exception: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF4rJ.png)

Comment: Please give the exceptions as text and not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is missing the dependency `rinsim-core` with groupId `com.github.rinde`.

Check with `dependency:list` if it is present. If not, add it.

If it is already there, try to compile the project outside eclipse. Install a command line maven, navigate to the directory, do `mvn clean package` and report any error you get as a comment under this answer.

Comment: No errors, only warnings: 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mas ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

Comment: This means that your build indeed has the right dependencies. If you stil experience problems inside eclipse then your eclipse is broken.

Comment: I re-installed eclipse yesterday, and I tried IntelliJ. Same problem.

Comment: But you checked that `rinsim-core` is in the dependency:list?

Comment: Yes, and it wasn't, so then I added it. No difference though.

Comment: And you still get the very same classnotfound?

Comment: Did you try to right click on the project -> Maven -> Update project.. (make sure "Clean projects" is checked) -> Ok?
Did you try if this also happens with RinSim v4.4.5?
Did you try removing your .m2 folder as is described in [RinSim troubleshooting](http://rinsim.rinde.nl/installation/troubleshooting/)?